# Cannot build sphinx autodocumentation with Django via GitLab (docker) pipeline

Tags: python, django, gitlab, python-sphinx, gitlab-ci-runner

this problem might be quite specific.

#### My setup

This is my project structure. It's a Django project.

```
├── docs
│   ├── build
│   │   ├── doctrees
│   │   └── html
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── source
│       ├── code
│       ├── conf.py
│       ├── contributing.md
│       ├── index.rst
│       ├── infrastructure.md
│       └── _static
├── my-project-name
│   ├── api.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── celeryconfig.py
│   ├── celery.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── routers.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
|   ... some more apps
```

It is hosted on a private GitLab instance and I have multiple runners installed. One is a docker executor that is responsible for building the documentation via Sphinx.

The basic `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
image: python:3.10-slim

stages:
- deploy

pages:
  tags:
  - docs
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - python3 -m pip install django sphinx furo myst-parser
  - sphinx-build -b html docs/source public/
```

This has been working just fine as long as I haven't tried to include Django code via the `sphinx-autodoc` extension. Everything shows up on the GitLab pages. I know that Sphinx needs to load every module that it scans upfront. So this is why you have to initialize Django in the `conf.py`.

The beginning of my Sphinx `conf.py` looks like this:

```py
# Sphinx needs Django loaded to correctly use the "autodoc" extension
import django
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my-project-name.settings")
sys.path.append(Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent)

django.setup()
```

The last line before calling `django.setup()` makes sure to include the project-level path.
Autodocumenting Django works fine with these modifications when I `make html` on my local system. The modules I specify are documented nicely and no errors occur.

##### Now to my actual problem

I push the code to my GitLab repository and let the jobs run via a docker executor.

```bash
$ python3 -m pip install django sphinx furo myst-parser
Collecting django
  Downloading Django-4.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (8.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 8.1/8.1 MB 124.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting sphinx
  Downloading sphinx-6.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (3.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.0/3.0 MB 111.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
...
# the loading continues here
```

After all the modules are loaded it tries to execute Sphinx. Now, this error occurs:

```bash
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.0.1
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
$ sphinx-build -b html docs/source public/
Running Sphinx v6.1.3
######
/builds/my-dir/my-project-name
######
Configuration error:
There is a programmable error in your configuration file:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sphinx/config.py", line 351, in eval_config_file
    exec(code, namespace)  # NoQA: S102
  File "/builds/my-dir/my-project-name/docs/source/conf.py", line 22, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my-project-name'
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

As far as I know, this usually occurs when you don't set your path variables correctly. But I set it at the project level and print it out as validation (the `### lines` in the error message). My project path is definitely `/builds/my-dir/my-project-name`.

Do you have any ideas on what I could try to make it work?

Comment: Yeah. `Path` objects don't work in `sys.path` -- you need a string in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ok - I'm a major idiot.

```py
sys.path.append(Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent.as_posix())
```

saved the day.